# Is it possible to trace the detail of third party everytime,when the third party perform any event to our server using sentry?

Tags: laravel, docker, sentry, laravel-echo

I want to trace the detail of third party if any action is perform in out server by third party.Need Help.

Comment: Do you want to save all requests?

Comment: Yes along with detail information such as IP,Application-URL,API-URL,tokens used...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.
There is a wonderful package. You can check the laravel telescope.
[Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope)

Also, You can add middleware to some routes that you want to save data.
In the middleware, you can save data to the database, or if you want to save data by laravel log, you can create a custom channel in config/logging.php like this:

```
    'channels' => [
        'your_channel_name' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/request/request.log'), // Your customer path
        ]
    ]
```

And your middleware will be like this (If you want to handle it by logs):

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $yourData = $request->all() // + ip and etc.
        Log::channel('your_channel_name')->info($yourData);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

It handles your data by laravel log.

I hope it is useful.